# Is {1, 2} a value? If yes, what is its type? If no, why can it be assigned to an initializer list?

Tags: c++, c++11, types, type-conversion, initializer-list

```
#include <initializer_list>

using namespace std;

template<class T>
void f(initializer_list<T>)
{}

int main()
{
    typeid(1);           // OK
    typeid(int);         // OK
    typeid(decltype(1)); // OK

    f({1, 2}); // OK

    typeid({1, 2});           // error
    decltype({1, 2}) v;       // error
    typeid(decltype({1, 2})); // error
}
```

Is {1, 2} a value?

If yes, why is typeid({1, 2}); not legal?

If no, why can it be assigned to an initializer_list object?

Comment: Clang 3.4 puts it pretty clearly. Those need expressions.

Comment: `{1,2}` is not an expression.

Comment: I think the Standard uses the term *value* only/mostly in the context of *value of an object*. There's also the *value category of an expression* (like rvalue and lvalue). `{1,2}` is neither an object nor an expression, therefore I don't think it could be named a *value*.

Comment: @DyP *prvalues* are by definition values without objects. An object is defined by having an address, placing it into the lvalue category. But yeah, initializer lists are merely instructions for forming a value that you might want to have.

Comment: @Potatoswatter "An object is defined by having an address" that would make temporaries non-objects. Literals are clearly non-objects, but have a type and a value category. I think it wouldn't be wrong to say they have a value, too. But maybe, they just *are* values?

Comment: @DyP They're prvalues. A temporary need not have object representation in a context where you cannot apply unary `&` to it. Once you bind a reference to it, it's not a prvalue any more. Value category is a property of an expression. Expressions evaluate to values which may or may not be objects.

Answer (score 4):

1. No, it is a syntactic construct with no intrinsic value. It's not even (syntactically) an expression. But it can be used to initialize an object.

   The `typeid` operator requires a proper expression, but function arguments do not. When you pass a function argument, you are actually initializing the parameter object.
2. `initializer_list` can be initialized by such a thing. Arrays can also be initialized by braced initializer lists. The list is used to initialize an array accessed through the `initializer_list`.

Confusingly, `auto x = { 1, 2, 3 };` causes `x` to be declared as an `std::initializer_list< int >`. This is a special exception where `auto` differs from `decltype`, and it has been proposed for deprecation. There are few good uses for persistent `initializer_list`s.

Answer (score 0):

`typeid` needs an expression

Form [here](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/typeid)

The `typeid` expression is lvalue expression which refers to a static object of the polymorphic type `const std::type_info` or of some type derived from it.

Syntax: *typeid( expression )*

Examines the expression *expression*

- the typeid expression evaluates the *expression* and then refers to the `std::type_info` object that represents the dynamic type of the expression.
- If expression is not a glvalue *expression* of polymorphic type, typeid does not evaluate the expression, and the `std::type_info` object it identifies represents the static type of the expression.

Comment: But `{ … }` isn't an expression, so you can already stop before any value category stuff.